# Why custom subclass of UIScrollView in Swift have to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

Objective-C code:

```
#import "CZScrollView.h"

@implementation CZScrollView

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"it works");
    return false;
}

@end
```

Swift code:

```
import UIKit

class CZScrollView: UIScrollView,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        print("it works")
        return false
    }
}
```

I need to identify other gestures and decide my scrollview's behavior. So I need to create a subclass of UIScrollView and add my code in the method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

First, the Objective-C code and the Swift code can realize my need. But there is something strange in the Swift code. If you don't declare the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, the method would not be run. Why is this?

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Please [edit] your question by copying and pasting your relevant code into your question as properly formatted text. Pictures are hard to read, can't be searched, and can't be referenced in answers.

Comment: But the something strange is in the swift code, if you don't declare the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, the method would not be run, this is why? Please clarify this phrase . What is your actual problem ?

Comment: I just declare UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to subclass,  add one method of it, nothing more, why the method could be run?

Comment: @rmaddy this look better, thank you. no next.

Comment: It may be have something to do with the type system. In ObjC the runtime system will be actively asked, whether the target object implements the delegate method (via `respondsToSelector`). Keep in mind, that in ObjC it is possible to add method implementations at runtime, i.e. it cannot be decided at compile time, whether the delegate method is implemented or not. This is not the case for Swift. I.e. you explicitly declare protocols. Whether protocols methods are implemented can be decided at compile time.

Comment: @mschmidt there are some double for me, but thanks your analyse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that in the internal swift code of `UIScrollView` there could be something like this:

```
if let gestureRecognizerDelegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
   // Do whatever
}
```

If you don't explicitly mark your class as conforming to the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol, that check will fail.

Comment: I think @mschmidt's comment above is more detailed, there still something i can't explicitly know.